# Why is style *{display:*} included in the HTML body?

Tags: html, css

When I add such CSS into `<style>` tags:

```
* {
    display:block;
}
```

It is *never* interpreted correctly. Instead, what do I see? Somehow everything inside `<style>` becomes the part of html body. E.g.:

```css
* {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<p>paragraph</p>
<phrase>phrase</phrase>
<pet>pet</pet>
```

This happens anywhere. For the first time, I thought this is the problem with StackSnippets. (i.e. the live demo for Stack Overflow, the one I've provided above), but then I checked with code pen. Then with jsfiddle. Then I've gone ahead and made a file on my server, giving it all contents I inserted in the snippet above.

The outcome is always the same. The CSS gets included in the html, *though it is applied.* (the only fix is to create a stylesheet and include it using `<link>`)

The most interesting thing, is, that it seem to happen only with `display:*`. E.g., the following works:

```css
* {
    color:green;
    background:red;
    border:2px solid orange;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

```html
<p>paragraph</p>
<phrase>phrase</phrase>
<pet>pet</pet>
```

But once I put in the styles of the last snippet `display:*`, the styles are, again, magically included in HTML.

```css
* {
    color:green;
    background:red;
    border:2px solid orange;
    border-radius:5px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>paragraph</p>
<phrase>phrase</phrase>
<pet>pet</pet>
```

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's styling the `<head>` element and everything in it, including the very `<style>` element your CSS resides in, because the CSS appears as character data within the `<style>` element. A `<link>` element on the other hand doesn't have any content — it points to a separate resource altogether, so there is nothing inside the element itself to be displayed.

Most browsers implement `<head>` as `display: none` (and some propagate that value to every descendant), which you are able to override by targeting them with a `display` style. The rest of the properties are still applied to `<head>` and its descendants regardless of whether you do this, but without it, they simply won't show up in your page so you don't really see it happening. That's really all there is to it — there isn't anything else that's special about `<head>` or its related elements.

In other words, as far as CSS is concerned, the following (yes, a `<style>` element with a `style` attribute...):

```html
<style style="display: block; font-family: monospace">
p { color: red; }
</style>
```

Is no different from this:

```html
<code style="display: block; font-family: monospace">
p { color: red; }
</code>
```

Comment: I mentioned: "the only fix is to create a stylesheet and include it using <link>" - why does it work then?

Comment: Still, I don't really get the fact about <link>. Yes, I realize there's nothing in the stylesheet itself to be styled, but the stylesheet still applies styling to any elements, but somehow it's applies only to the elements in the body.

Comment: Ah, I got it! So the stylesheet styles the head anyway, but unless there's any text in it, nothing is displayed. Setting the <title> and using stylesheet makes the <title> display.

Comment: @the because I haven't included the title in the demos?