# When should <script> tags be visible and why can they?

Tags: html, css, script-tag

A `script` element that got styled as `display:block` appears visible. Why is it possible and is there any real use case where it is desired?

```css
td > * {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var test = 1;
      </script>von 1
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have seen a visible CSS `<style>` with content editable. Nice way to see the effects in real time.

Comment: For your next challenge, devise a way to make comments visible.

Comment: Came here to mention the same thing, @JanDvorak. Blew my min the first time I saw it. I've got a demonstration of this on [codepen](http://codepen.io/KjeldSchmidt/pen/vKmaJL)

Comment: Reminds me of *The Voyage of the Dawn Treader* when Lucy reads a spell that makes Aslan visible, and she's surprised that magic would affect *him*, and he basically says, did you think I would disobey my own rules?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324387/why-is-style-display-included-in-the-html-body

Comment: I came in here thinking this was a basic question and left having learned something new. I <3 sof.

Comment: Another example why visible script can be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57343612/985399

Comment: One possible use case is literate programming, you can write a document describing your program or web app, including visible scripts and styles.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

The HTML5 specification [defines a style sheet](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/rendering.html#the-css-user-agent-style-sheet-and-presentational-hints) that user agents (like browsers) are expected to use. [Section 10.3.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/rendering.html#hidden-elements) lists the styles for "Hidden elements":

> ```css
> @namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
>
> [hidden], area, base, basefont, datalist, head, link,
> meta, noembed, noframes, param, rp, script, source, style, template, track, title {
>   display: none;
> }
>
> embed[hidden] { display: inline; height: 0; width: 0; }
> ```

As you can see, it applies `display: none;` to `script`.

**This is the only "barrier" between your users and hidden `script` elements.** It’s perfectly fine and intended to be able to overwrite styles from user-agent style sheets within author style sheets (and of course also within user style sheets).

Why someone might want to use it?  One use case is [displaying content without having to escape characters like `<`/`>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16115085/1591669), similar to the old `xmp` element. The `script` element can be used not only for scripts, but [also for data blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14428316/1591669) (i.e., for anything with a MIME type).

Comment: The data has to be already coded into the `<script>` - data blocks can not be loaded by `src`.

Comment: @PauliSudarshanTerho: Yes, if used as data block, the `src` attribute is not allowed on the `script` element.

Answer (score 70):

> Why can `<script>` Tags be visible?

Because they are HTML elements like any other and there is no reason to write special case rules in the HTML specification (which would add complexity) to prevent CSS from applying to them.

Any element can be styled. Take, for example:

```
head { display: block; }
title { display: block; }
meta { display: block; }
meta[charset]:after { display: block; content: attr(charset); }
meta[content]:after { display: block; content: attr(content); }
```

> Is there any Usecase where it is wanted?

Certainly no common ones, but general rules aren't designed to make sense for *everything* that you *can* apply them to. They are designed for the common cases.

Comment: In fact if you look at a script tag in the Chrome inspector, you see `user agent stylesheet: script {display:none}`

Comment: I'd make that "DOM elements like any other". In fact they are quite special HTML tags with their parsing rules.

Comment: Fun fact: since script contents are parsed as CDATA, you can use `<script type="text/plain">` like you could `<xmp>` in the past, but still be compatible with the W3C validator.

Comment: why does `script {display: block !important;}` not work when there is no special case rule?

Comment: @wutzebaer It works fine for me. Are you sure you're doing everything right? Note that the `script` tag must be in a visible element as well - it will only show you `script`s in body, not e.g. `head` by default.

Answer (score 36):

Another (not common) use case:

I sometimes use `<script>` tags for brief HTML code examples in style guides. That way I don't have to escape HTML tags and special characters. And text editor tag autocomplete and syntax highlighting still work. But there's no easy way to add syntax highlighting in the browser.

```css
script[type="text/example"] {
    background-color: #33373c;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #aed9ef;
    display: block;
    font-family: monospace;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2px 10px 16px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-break: break-all;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<p>Here comes a code example:</p>
<script type="text/example">
  <div class="cool-component">
     Some code example
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Not bad, although I would suggest using a valid MIME-type: `text/html`, and using something like `class="codesample"` for applying styles. Just for pedantic reasons :D

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: It's probably safer *not* to use a "real" MIME type (or anything that might become one in the future), just in case some browser some day might decide to parse and execute script elements of that type in some manner. That said, I'd prefer to use the standard `x-` prefix for custom types, i.e. make it `text/x-example`.

Answer (score 14):

Possible use case: for debugging purposes.

You could apply a class at the document level, eg. `<body class="debugscript">`, then use some CSS:

```
body.debugscript script {
    display: block;
    background: #fcc;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 2px;
}
body.debugscript script:before {
    content: 'Script:';
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
}
body.debugscript script[src]:before {
    content: 'Script: ' attr(src);
}
```

Comment: Why not `<html class="debugscript">`?

Comment: @Bergi That's an option too, although it probably won't reveal `<head>` scripts because the `<head>` itself also has `display:none` so you'd need to forcibly reveal that, which could lead to further complications.

Comment: You mean "further fun" or "further debugging potential" :-)

Answer (score 1):

Script tags are hidden by default by using `display:none;`. Unor<sup>1</sup> explains the underlying language specification. However, they are still part of the DOM and can be styled accordingly.

That said, it is important to keep in mind exactly what a script tag is doing. While it used to be accompanied by types and languages, that is no longer required. It is now assumed that JavaScript is in there, and as a result browsers will interpret and execute the script as it is encountered (or loaded) from these tags.

**Once the script has been executed, the content of the tag is only text (often hidden) on the page.** This text can be revealed, but *it can also be removed* because it is just text.

At the bottom of your page, right before the closing `</html>` tag, you could very easily remove these tags along with their text and there would be no changes to the page.

For example:

```
(function(){
    var scripts = document.querySelectorAll("script");
    for(var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++){
        scripts[i].parentNode.removeChild(scripts[i]);
    }
})()
```

This will not remove any functionality, as the state of the page has already been altered and is reflected in the current global execution context. For example, if the page had loaded a library such as jQuery, removing the tags will not mean that jQuery is no longer exposed because it has already been added to the page's runtime environment. It is essentially only making the DOM inspection tool not show script elements, but it does highlight that the script elements once executed really are only text.

<sub>1. unor, Thu Jul 07 2016, wutzebaer, "When should  tags be visible and why can they?", Jul 1 at 10:53, https://stackoverflow.com/a/38147398/1026459</sub>