# I am adding the code in weebly but it dosent show up

Tags: json-ld, weebly

Issue with JSON LD CODE

To start with I am trying to use this code in weebly, buy using embed code option and then I click on the edit custom HTML and enter this code. However, after entering this nothing shows up as in the recipe is not shown on the page and a blank page is shown.
this code is picked on schema.org, for recipes.
Could anyone please help me out in what exactly went wrong. I really appreciate your assistance. FYI- I am new to this. I am trying to set up my own food website and and wanted to schema to for SEO improvement. Any other suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Please refer this link for the JSON-LD CODE. IT WILL BE AT THE END OF THE PAGE. https://schema.org/Recipe

Comment: "a blank page is shown": Was the page blank before, too?

Comment: Hi there....Yes, the page is blank..In weebly I need to drag an option called embed code and I need to edit it by applying code...so that in the UI the recipe appears

Answer (score 0):

When you add a JSON-LD block in the HTML, it doesn’t change anything visibly on the page. The `script` element is [hidden by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38147398/1591669) in all browsers, and you typically want to keep it like that (users typically have no interest in your JSON-LD code).

To check if adding the JSON-LD worked correctly, open the page in a browser and check the source code of the page. You should see the `script` element with your JSON-LD.

You have to add the content (that should be visible to your users) regularly with HTML. The JSON-LD exists next to your content (duplicating the data like name, photo URL etc.), it doesn’t replace your content.

Comment: Sounds interesting and thanks for your reply.I would appreciate if you could provide an example using the provided with the HTML. It would really be helpful for me to figure things out on how to write this html along with JSON-LD. .

Comment: please try to use to the recipe example as in schema.org..would be super helpful...Its a humble request.